# "Micro-Site" Options

Tags: plugins, multisite, multisite-user-management

We are wanting to start offering Micro-Sites as an option to member in a non-commercial environment. Essentially, each user ideally would have one page to customize the content for. Backgrounds and template options are not a priority as of now.

Can someone please recommend some options, if not alternatives if micro-sites are not plausible for a WordPress engine? I was looking around for options, but do not see many for this kind of scheme.

Thank you.

Comment: So basically you have a website powered by WordPress, and you want a user to be able to login. Each user is given a page and can edit it. IMO the microsite part is just confusing as it means different things to different people. "How do I create a page when users login" and "how do I allow users to edit a single page and no others" would be better questions to ask and get you much more comprehensive answers too

Comment: Without knowing more, this might be something where you'd want to use WordPress Multisite and give each user their own site. Or if it's a single page per user it may be simpler to stick with a single install and just give them their own page using their username as a slug or something of that nature. Yes, WordPress can do what you're asking - you're welcome to come back as you have more specific questions along the way.